# How to receive http request in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-7

Which component is best to use for receiving HTTP requests in Delphi application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) is the way to go. but you need a server component, not a client one. [TIDHTTPServer](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdHTTPServer.html) should fit the bill

Answer (score 6):

Let's not forget the [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html). Maybe not so simple to use as Indy, but very powerful. Supports http and https.

Answer (score 2):

Another option which is quite easy to use is the [Synapse TCP/IP](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) library. There are some examples available which show the usage of it as a HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with HTTP components before, and I've also implemented IInternetProtocol to integrate with Internet Explorer and build ISAPI extensions to integrate with IIS.
I've started http://xxm.sourceforge.net/ to open-source this, and combine it with a generic interface, a pre-parser and an auto-compile option, so I could join HTML and Delphi into the same source-files and code websites much like PHP, Cold Fusion and oldskool ASP.